# send TCP messages from two different threads

Tags: android, design-patterns, tcp

I have two threads that need to send TCP messages using the same already stablished connection. I have an object lets say tcpSender that I would like to use from booth threads. How can I design my software in order I would not have concurrency problems and lost messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could model this as a producer/consumer where each thread injects messages into the `TCPSender` whenever they are ready and the `TCPSender` maintains a FIFO queue of messages. The insertions into the queue would be locked (within the `TCPSender`) and processed in-order.

There would be another thread that is *consuming* the messages when the queue is not empty locking each time a message is removed from the queue.

Two immediate benefits are that you can support an arbitrary number of producers and the blocking is limited to inserting into a queue and not to actually sending the messages (from the point of view of the producer, that is).

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) which you [`acquire`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire%28%29) before each send, and [`release`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release%28%29) after each send. This would ensure that the resources is accessed by one thread at a time.

Comment: +1 Yes. Just be aware that the send operation can block for an arbitrarily long time (if, for example, the other end of the connection stops accepting data and TCP flow control kicks in), so you could be waiting a long time to `acquire` the semaphore.

Comment: That's unnecessarily complex. A Semaphore is in Java usually only required if you want to limit a specific number of simultaneous accesses. If only one thread is allowed access to a resource, a synchronized block is much easier to use.

Comment: but what happens if one thread needs to send while the object is blocked?

Comment: @jarnbjo, no, that only works if the method is static, which I doubt it is here, since biquillo talks about objects.

Comment: @biquillo: If someone already has the semaphore (is sending) then the other thread will block in the `acquire` method, until the other thread calls `release`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to get an answer after sending this data, you can use a queue.